# How to use Express in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

While using express in Node.js how to connect it with the client?

Do we need a .js file to be included in on the client side?

The goal is to make a client side with a "connec"t button and when I click that button the client is connected to the server and the server return is alerted on the page.

```
var app = require('express').createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});
app.get('message', function(req, res){
console.log(req);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Express is a web development framework (the intended client is a web browser).

In the application's root directory type `node app.js` and then open http://localhost:3000 in your browser

Answer (score 0):

you can add jade file in the view folder and add the button to it and on click event , give the url to be called if that url matched with the app.get of the server code, do the work and after finishing render it back to the page u want with changes.

for rendering use res.render('index');

u can also pass results with it,

res.render('index',{result:result});